# Boolean to Cursor Converter in Xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have written a converter class inheriting from `IValueConverter`. When I bind the cursor of a control to a CheckBox or ToggleButton's `Ischecked` property using this converter, nothing happens. Here is my `BooleanToCursorConverter` class:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Machine_Vision
{
    [ValueConversion(typeof(bool?), typeof(CursorType))]
    public class BooleanToCursorConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if ((bool?)value==true)
            {
                return CursorType.Cross;
            }
            else
            {
                return CursorType.Arrow;
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my XAML code (simplified):

```html
<Window x:Class="Machine_Vision.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Machine_Vision"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="650"
        Width="1300"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        WindowState="Maximized"
        Closing="Window_Closing">
    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="B2V" />
        <local:BooleanToCursorConverter x:Key="C2V" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Image x:Name="Original_View"
               Cursor="{Binding IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource C2V}, ElementName=DrawPoints}" />
        <ToggleButton x:Name="DrawPoints"
                      Content="Draw Points"
                      Margin="5" />
     <Grid/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning the wrong type of value from your converter. The `Cursor` property can only be set to a `System.Windows.Input.Cursor`:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(bool?), typeof(Cursor))]
public class BooleanToCursorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((bool?)value == true)
        {
            return Cursors.Cross;
        }
        else
        {
            return Cursors.Arrow;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: that's it, but why its not accepting the enumeration value?

Comment: Because the Convert method returns an object, i.e. you can return any value from the converter but you can still only set the Cursor property to a Cursor value.